# Send variable value to onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table, and in each cell there is an edit image, so when users click on it, they will see an input box in the cell. (The following is an example of one of the cells)

```
  <td>
      echo  
           "<p id=$idl>" . $var  .   "</p>" . "<img style ='cursor:pointer; ' class='onInput' src='http://nimbuzz007.hexat.com/icon4/icon%2015.png' id='input_img' onclick='legacyFunction($idl,$var)'>";

   </td>
```

and this is the 'legacyFunction':

```
 function legacyFunction($idl,$var) {

    document.getElementById($idl).innerHTML =
    "<input  value=$var></input>";
```

};

so I want to send the current data of the cell to the function, to show that in the input box But it does not work. What is my mistake? is it possible to do that?

Comment: Mixing Javascript, HTML and PHP is the first of many issues here...

Comment: Mixing JS and PHP is sometimes good, but in this case Something Is Wrong[tm].

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the arguments, since they're strings.

```
onclick='legacyFunction(\"$idl\",\"$var\")'
```

Answer (score 0):

As other have stated its a bad practice to mix html, js and php. I always tend to separate the code when possible.

Example:

```
<td>
    <p id="<?php echo $idl; ?>"><?php echo $var; ?></p>
    <img style="cursor: pointer;" class="onInput" src="http://nimbuzz007.hexat.com/icon4/icon%2015.png" onclick="legacyFunction(<?php echo "$idl, $var"; ?>);">
</td>
<script>
    function legacyFunction($idl, $var) {
        // Inputs are void elements and as such they do not need closing tags - </input>
        document.getElementById($idl).innerHTML =  '<input value="'+ $var + '">';
    };
</script>
```